# Quit function for python 2

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm following a tutorial in python 3 but using python 2. In the tutorial the following code is used:

```
button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Disagree", command = quit)
```

When I run the code I get the error:

```
NameError: global name 'quit' is not defined
```

Is there an equivalent function I could use in python 2? I tried sys.exit() but that froze the tkinter window rather than just closing it out.

Comment: Then I don't know what the problem is... I'm working with the Canopy distribution..

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter wants root.quit(). (root is the root Tkinter object)